# TLS handshake fails intermittently when using HAProxy Ingress Controller

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, haproxy-ingress

I'm using HAProxy Ingress Controller (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/haproxy-ingress) for TLS-termination for my app.
I have a simple Node.JS server listening on 8080 for HTTP, and 1935 as a simple echo server (not HTTP).
And I use HAProxy Ingress controller to wrap the ports in TLS. (8080 -> 443 (HTTPS), 1935 -> 1936 (TCP + TLS))
I installed HAProxy Ingress Controller with

```
helm upgrade --install haproxy-ingress incubator/haproxy-ingress \
   --namespace test \
  -f ./haproxy-ingress-values.yaml \
  --version v0.0.27
```

, where the content of `haproxy-ingress-values.yaml` is

```
controller:
  ingressClass: haproxy
  replicaCount: 1
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
  tcp:
    1936: "test/simple-server:1935:::test/ingress-cert"
  nodeSelector:
    "kubernetes.io/os": linux
defaultBackend:
  nodeSelector:
    "kubernetes.io/os": linux
```

And here's my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "haproxy"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    secretName: ingress-cert
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: "simple-server"
            servicePort: 8080
```

The cert is self-signed.
If I test the TLS handshake with

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect "<IP>":1936
```

Sometimes (about 1/3 of the times) it fails with

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
139828847829440:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 316 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

The same problem doesn't happen for 443 port.
See [here](https://github.com/hanshsieh/misc/tree/haproxy-ingress-tls) for the details of the settings to reproduce the problem.

**[edit]**
As pointed out by @JoaoMorais, it's because the default statistic port is 1936.
Although I didn't turn on statistics, it seems like it still interferes with the behavior.
There're two solutions that work for me.

- Change my service's 1936 port to another
- Change the stats port by adding values like below when installing the haproxy-ingress chart.

```
controller:
  stats:
    port: 5000
```

Comment: port `1936` is already used for stats, can you reproduce the problem with another external/listening port number?

Comment: @JoaoMorais Thank you. Changing 1936 port to other port or changing the stats port work! Please reply to this question so that I can mark your answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAProxy by default allows to reuse the same port number across the same or other frontend/listen sections and also across other haproxy process. This can be changed adding [noreuseport](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#noreuseport) in the `global` section.

The default HAProxy Ingress configuration uses port number `1936` to expose stats. If such port number is reused by eg a tcp proxy, the incoming requests will be distributed between both frontends - sometimes your service will be called, sometimes the stats page. Changing the tcp proxy or the stats page (doc [here](https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/docs/configuration/keys/#stats)) to another port should solve the issue.